# python about train a deep neural network on the MRI slices dataset

Tags: python, mri

I want to Train a deep neural network on the MRI slices dataset. Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

file_dir = 'C:\\Users\\adam\\Downloads\\MRI_Images\\'

import glob
import cv2

images = [cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob("C:\\Users\\adam\\Downloads\\MRI_Images\\.png")]

(X_train_full, y_train_full), (X_test, y_test) = images
```

And python shows that not enough values to unpack. I don't know why. Is there problem when I put all images in one file to python?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the structure of your dataset directory, but I know that using `glob.glob()` will return all the images inside the `'C:\\Users\\adam\\Downloads\\MRI_Images\\'` folder (not include subfolder).

That is, what you get inside `image` is a list of read-in images (numpy array format), like:

```py
[image_0, image_1, ...]
```

A list can not be unpack into two tuples. And this is **why the error comes out**.

Try reading your train and test images seperately might help:

```py
images_trainx = [cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob("C:\\Users\\adam\\Downloads\\MRI_Images\\trainx\\*.png")]
images_trainy = [cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob("C:\\Users\\adam\\Downloads\\MRI_Images\\trainy\\*.png")]
images_testx = [cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob("C:\\Users\\adam\\Downloads\\MRI_Images\\testx\\*.png")]
images_testy = [cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob("C:\\Users\\adam\\Downloads\\MRI_Images\\testy\\*.png")]
```

This approach is clunky but hard to go wrong.